# django 1.8.13 'User' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with the method Login(), the variable 'user' if it contains the user but that method fails. could help detect the problem.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def login(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render(request, 'Default.html')

mensaje = ''
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    User = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if User is not None:
        if User.is_active:
            login(User)
            return render(request, 'Default.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'mensaje':mensaje})
    else:
return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'mensaje':mensaje})
```

Comment: like this in the documentation also fails to send two parameters in the method login ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing login from django.contrib.auth but look at your very next line of code.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'Default.html')
```

Yep, you are shadowing that login method with one for your own. The solution would be to rename your own funciton

```
def my_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'Default.html')
```

Comment: Exactly, you 're absolutely right , there was given me realize that, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Also, according to the documentation, [`login()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) function *expects 2 arguments* to be passed in - a request instance and a user model instance:

```
login(request, User)
```

Comment: so the first thing but I declare under this fails - "login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"...